# FInd immediate large and small number for a number from an unsorted list without sorting?

Tags: sorting, mergesort

I am trying to write a function that takes a number as input and outputs the previous and next numbers from an unsorted list in sorted order. e.g if the list is [29,1,49,8] , calling the function(8) should return [1,29]
Only possible solution with minimum avg complexity is by doing sorting,are there any other methods,which have less avg complexity?The list is randomly generated of a fixed size of 100

Comment: What if there is no number less than (or greater than) the requested value. That is, what if your list is `[29, 1, 49, 8]` and the call is `function(50)`? Also, will there be more than one function call per list?

Comment: Oh! I didnt even think about that scenario,then we have to first check whether the element exists or not and then proceed i guess.I am assuming there will be a function but it might call or may not functions in itself.Any suggestions Jim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to sort.
Just pass through the array and maintain best_delta_positive and best_delta_negative, together with the indices where they were found if necessary.

Comment: Will that work if the list is [29,22,65,8] where there is no delta negative?.The list is randomly generated

Comment: Awesome!,this will work in that situation.Thanks Malcolm